# Broken symlink file throws FileNotFoundException but passes File.Exists

Tags: c#, file, .net-core, symlink

I have a broken symbolic link:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mugen  staff     10 Nov  5  2018 README.md -> README.md?
```

A check of `File.Exists(filePath)` returns `true`, but calling `new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)` throws `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

What is the best strategy to avoid trying to open this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior kind of makes sense - the file (symbolic link) exists, but you can't read it because it points to a file that doesn't exist (broken symbolic link).

Personally, I'm not a big fan of these pre-checks. First, they are racy by nature - even if all the checks pass, something can happen on the file system after that and before you try using the file (admittedly, it's less of an issue in a local filesystem, but I still think it's a bad practice). Second, it's expensive - all these checks perform at least some I/O, and often redundantly so (since you'll perform the same I/O again when you open the file).

I'd just attempt to open the file, and catch the exception:

```
FileStream fs = null;
try {
    fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    // Use fs
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle the exception in some elegant way
} finally {
    if (fs != null) {
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *they are racy by nature - even if all the checks pass, something can happen*  It's worse than that.  It's a **BUG** that has [its own Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). The check is **NOT** the action, so passing the check is actually meaningless as to whether the action would succeed.  In this case, the file may actually exist, but the user may not have proper read or write permission. "So I'll add a check for that!"  Nope - you forgot about ACLs or read-only file systems.

Comment: (cont) The **only** definitive way to check if you can open a file is to actually open the file.